# How to use innerHTML to show all the contents of a object

Tags: javascript

This is the code that i'm playing with that i'm having trouble with I will really appreciate it if some one show me how to do this.

```js
var student = {
name: "Dave ",
grades: [80, 85, 90 ,95]
};

for (prop_value_name in student ) {
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML= student;
}
```

```html
<p id="x"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for in` loop is wrong, the first argument in the `for in` is actually the property keys in your object, so if you want the values you need to use them with the object,

If you want to iterate over the object and display all values in one line you can do:

```js
  var student = {
    name: "Dave ",
    grades: [80, 85, 90 ,95]
    };
    
    for (index in student ) {
    document.getElementById("x").innerHTML += student[index];
    }
```

```html
  <p id="x"></p>
```

Now this won't work if one of the property is another object...

Comment: Thanks for your response every one and Pato Salazar your answer was what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: no problem... just remember that this will display the values... now if you have an object as the value of one of the property you will get `[object Object]` again

Comment: O wait I see what you mean by object object again so yeah I added a button to it just now and it keeps making copies of the same data every time I press the button is there a way to only show it once?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert that object into a string.  You can do this using `JSON.stringify`.  Also, when you loop like you were you are overwriting what you previously put there.  It would have only ended up with the last parsed property displayed.  When using `JSON.parse` you can pass a third argument for indentation.  When outputting multiple lines of text with whitespace you can instead use a `<pre>` tag for preformatted text.

Example:

```js
var student = {
  name: "Dave ",
  grades: [80, 85, 90 ,95]
};

document.getElementById("x").innerText = JSON.stringify(student, null, 2);

document.getElementById("y").innerText = Object.keys(student)
  .reduce((a, k) => {
    if (student[k] instanceof Array) {
      // If property is array use different format
      a += student[k].join(" ");
    } else {
      a += student[k];
    }
    return a;
  }, "");
```

```html
<pre id="x"></pre>
<div id="y"></div>
```

Comment: I don't want to show the curly braces or the quote characters tho or the commas I want it to show just the properties. like this Dave 80 85 90 95

Comment: Ok I will add something for this

Answer (score 0):

Json [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) can convert your js object to json

```js
 

  var student = {
  name: "Dave ",
  grades: [80, 85, 90 ,95]
  };
  var json = JSON.stringify(student);

  document.getElementById("x").innerText = json;
```

```html
<p id="x"></p>
```